# WebView Databinding only updating once

Tags: windows-phone-8, xamarin.forms

I currently have a WebView in XAML as shown here

```
<StackLayout>
  <WebView x:Name="PrimaryWebView" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <WebView.Source>
      <HtmlWebViewSource Html="{Binding Path=ViewModel.HtmlSource}" />
    </WebView.Source>
  </WebView>     
</StackLayout>
```

In my ViewModel I have

```
private String htmlSource = null;
    public String HtmlSource
    {
        get
        {

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(htmlSource))
            {

                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
                {
                    ScreenLoading();

                    var result = await contentController.Get(currentPage);
                    if (result != null)
                    {

                        HtmlSource = result.Content;
                        Heading = result.Name;

                    }

                    ScreenFinished();

                });

                // Returns empty while loading
                return contentController.GetBlank();
            }

            // returns here once htmlSource is no longer empty
            return htmlSource;

        }
        set
        {
            htmlSource = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => HtmlSource);

        }
    }
```

In my View I have this to fix a known bug

```
    /// <summary>
    /// FIX: Due to bug https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=21699
    /// </summary>
    protected override void OnBindingContextChanged()
    {
        base.OnBindingContextChanged();

        PrimaryWebView.Source.BindingContext = BindingContext;
    }
```

On the first page load

1. My ScreenLoading works by showing a loading screen
2. The GetBlank() works and fills the WebView correctly (I have filled this with just dummy data to test)
3. ScreenFinished correctly runs and removes the loading screen.
4. THE ISSUE: The WebView doesn't update with the new content once it correctly returns.

Maybe I have this approach all wrong, i'm not sure but the fact that the ScreenLoading and ScreenFinished is all working correctly, as they change bindable properties that correctly update on screen, i'm wondering why the HtmlSource isn't doing the same.

Comment: Also just to note that the Heading property that is also updated correctly binds and updates the screen when complete. Meaning it is specifically something to do with the HtmlWebViewSource on a WebView, possibly just on Windows Phone, can't test it on Android at the moment because my trial expired and just waiting on an invoice payment until I can fork out for a business license.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a way to get it to update but I don't like it at all. I have updated the OnBindingContextChanged to detect when the property is changed, then rebind it to a new source. It works but if anyone has a better way or why this is happening in the first place please let me know.

```
 /// <summary>
 /// FIX: Due to bug https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=21699
 /// </summary>
 protected override void OnBindingContextChanged()
 {
     base.OnBindingContextChanged();

     PrimaryWebView.Source.BindingContext = BindingContext;
     PrimaryWebView.Source.PropertyChanged += (sender, e) =>
     {

          PrimaryWebView.Source = new HtmlWebViewSource() { BindingContext = BindingContext, Html = ((PolicyViewModel)BindingContext).HtmlSource};

      };
  }
```